# How to design and build RF amplifier, that work in 450Khz

Tags: transmitter, power-amplifier

I have a schematic, that is a sine generator and mixer that does AM  modulation. How to design and build an RF power amplifier and build a compact antenna. The goal is to transmit signal up to 50 meters. So the amplifier should be enough power. 
I plan to use only fixed frequency, that radiate device, it's about 450Khz.

Comment: A lot of people would not call that RF. Is it legal in your area to even do that?

Comment: That starts to get to a distance where this would probably not be possible without either fairly careful engineering or an Amateur Radio license (and for legal uses thereof).  If you have that license you you know where to start on researching this.  The question is too broad to fit here.  **For a practical need chose a frequency where your goal is legal and off the shelf solutions are readily available**.

Comment: No problem with license.

Comment: I have some experience with build FM-transmitter, but that experience only how to make layout.

Comment: Can you just use electric-field coupling? Assume 10Kohm impedance at 450KHz, resonant, with 10KHz bandwidth. Total RX noise is 12nanoVolts * sqrt(10KHZ) = 1.2 microVolts. Assume need 20dB SNR, so need 12 microVolts induced from TX to RX, 50 meters away. If the universe is **only** two metal plates 50 meters apart, there will be lots of coupling. To get 12uV across 10Kohm, you need 1.2 nanoAmps displacement current. Assume 0.1pF coupling across 50 meters (large plates). You need about 10,000 volts/second slewRate, using I = C * dV/dT. But what is legal?

Answer (score 1):

Since 455 kHz was commonly used for intermediate frequency (IF) amplifiers for AM medium-wave receivers, there are many schematics available, such as this from [Pan-Tex](http://www.pan-tex.net/usr/r/receivers/thirdif.htm),

[image: Pan-tex.net 3rd IF]

Or this from [Next.Gr](http://www.next.gr/rf/am-circuits/AM-radio-intermediate-frequency-amplification-and-detection-circuit-l58967.html),

[image: Next.gr IF stage]

The output from either should be sufficient for short-range communication. Since a practical (and legal) antenna at this frequency is a small fraction of the wavelength, a sensitive and selective receiver is needed. [Ceramic resonators](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075FQNPL3) give a sharp pass-band and might help in place of IF transformers.

That said, this is a busy frequency, and expect that there will be interference from MW radio oscillators and other devices.

Comment: This schematics from heterodyne receiver and amplifier signal after mixer. It's operates with low amplitude signal.

Comment: @user3771501, Correct: the range you require is 50 m. 20 mW or less should be be needed, which these IF amps can furnish.

Answer (score 1):

A compact antenna at 450 kHz won't transmit a proper EM wave. A proper antenna at 450 kHz (such as a quarter wave monopole) will be about 150 metres long so that doesn't count because, it's longer than the distance you wish to communicate therefore it isn't compact by any reasonable understanding of the word. So you have to try and communicate using H field or E field comms.

For H field comms that means you need a coil to generate a magnetic field and that magnetic field will deteriorate with distance cubed. So, if the H field is 1 amp per metre at 1 metre distant from the coil then at 50 metres the field is only 8 uA per metre.

So, design a magnetic receiver and ascertain what field intensity is needed to adequately get you above the noise floor then, work out what field intensity is needed at the transmitter.

Regards circuitry (as others have said), 450 kHz is not a challenge to any EE worth his salt and you will find that you have various technologies at your finger tips to choose from but, don't be under any illusion that you can use anything as small as a ferrite rod to transmit more than a couple of metres - they are great as receivers but they do not emit, in any pracical measure, anything other than magnetism and, the bigger the coil (diameter) the better they are.

At 450 kHz and 50 metres you are looking at near-field technology not radio technology.